# Free image for the "grab" cursor for IE11

Tags: images, icon, css, copyright, licensing

I am looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697067/css-for-grabbing-cursors-drag-drop/35517611) and its answers, and it seems the only legitimate way to implement a grab cursor in IE11 is to use an image like this:

```
 cursor: url(images/grab.cur);
```

Browsing the internet I don't find any such images for which I can be 100% sure that they are free to use without any obligations.

Does anyone know an image for "grab" cursor that is definitely free and without any obligations?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at these for background info:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207650/crossbrowser-grab-cursor-moz-webkit

https://caniuse.com/#search=cursor

https://codepen.io/benkalsky/pen/ByJawa

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

And from what I know, the grab cursor included as part of Webkit is freely useable as is - if I'm incorrect, or it's not to your taste, it's the work of a few minutes to create your open open-hand / grab cursor in Illustrator, Inkscape, Sketch app or Affinity Designer, and export as a `.png`, then use an online converter to make that into a `.cur` file.

Failing that, the Entypo+ glyph set is free to use, comes as sheer vector, and has a nice vector open hand glyph in it - easy to convert.

Also consider looking at the resources of [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/#) which are all royalty-free, open source, and pretty darn well developed.

Hope this helps.